# Set max value for color bar on seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, colorbar

I need to set the max value on the seaborn heatmap `cbar` to 2. I've tried:

```py
cbar_kws = { 'ticks' : [0, 2] }
sns.heatmap(tiles, robust=True, fmt="f", cmap= 'RdBu_r', cbar_kws = cbar_kws)
```

But this doesn't work and the documentation isn't very clear. How would I do this properly?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You want to use the `vmin` and `vmax` parameters for the heatmap, as described in the [docs](http://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

> **vmin, vmax** : floats, optional
>
> Values to anchor the colormap, otherwise they are inferred from the data and other keyword arguments.

```
sns.heatmap(tiles, robust=True, fmt="f", cmap='RdBu_r', vmin=0, vmax=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason, you want to set `vmin` and `vmax` after the `heatmap()` call, you can do so by calling `set_clim()` on the `QuadMesh` object (`heatmap()` calls `pcolormesh()` internally and its result resides in `Axes.collections`).

```py
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.heatmap([[x] for x in range(10)])
ax.collections[0].set_clim(0,2)               # set vmin and vmax
```

[image: result]

If you did not save the Axes that stores the heatmap, then

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.heatmap([[x] for x in range(10)])         # set vmin and vmax
plt.gca().collections[0].set_clim(0,2)
```